# Question: Assume S is an ordered set, and that a subset A of S has a least element. Show that for any s in S, {s} union A also has a least element.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

So I'm stuck writing a proof for the following statement:

Assume $S$ is an ordered set, and $A \subseteq S$ has a least element. Show that for any $s \in S$, $\{s\} \cup A$ also has a least element.

The solutions for this problem set only serve as a guide, which I'm finding rather frustrating. The solution says the following:

if $s \in A$, then $A=A \cup \{s\}$. If $s \notin A$, let $a \in A$ be the least element of $A$. According to the definiton of an ordering, either $s<a$ or $s>a$. Then show that $s$ is the least element of $A \cup \{s\}$ in the first case, and $a$ is the least element of $A \cup \{s\}$ in the second case.

Any tips on how to approach this would be incredibly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: "According to the definition of an ordering, either $s<a$ or $s>a$." This is true for linear orderings (aka, total orderings); that is the case of real numbers. It seems that in the text you are following, it either is linear or it's no order at all. Perhaps you should exclude the tag [tag:order-theory], since in that scope, your result is just false.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of understanding definitions.

Definition: Let $B$ be an ordered set. An element $b\in B$ is a least element if for every $b'\in B$ one has $b<b'$ or $b'=b$.

Here is how to complete the proof in the first case ($s<a$). Let $a\in A$ be a minimal element for $a$. If $s<a$ we claim that $s$ is minimal for $A$. Let $a'\in A\cup \{s\}$, if $a'\in A$ then either $a=a'$ and then $s<a'$ or $a<a'$ and then by transitivity, $s<a'$. Otherwise $a'=s$. We deduce that for every $a'\in A\cup\{s\}$ we have $s<a'$ or $s=a'$, hence by definition $s$ is minimal.

Comment: How do I know that either a=a' or a'=s? I know I'm missing something fundamental here. Thanks for the tips either way!

Comment: We start with $a'\in A\cup \{s\}$ so either $a'=s$ or $a'\in A$. Now, if $a'\in A$ then since it is a least element and $a$ is also a least element we must have that $a=a'$.